# Angular 2 i18n dynamic/instant translation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internationalization

I've followed the angular.io cookbook for internationalization (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#angular-i18n).
Everything works fine, and if I change my locale in the index.html file:

```
document.locale = 'en';
```

But I wish to change this dynamically, as we used to do in AngularJS. I have found several solutions, such as this:

```
//mycomponent.component.ts
changeLang(){
localStorage.setItem('localeId', "es");
location.reload(true);

} //I hardcoded the locale, but you get the idea
```

Is there a way to translate the document on the go? Because this solution is not practical, and has a long reload time. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 12):

In short it is not possible to change the locale without reloading the app as the translation work is done by `Angular` compiler.

---

As of today you have [two options](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-the-completed-translation-file-into-the-app) when using official `Angular i18n`:

### Use [AOT compiler](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-aot-compiler)

In this case a separate bundle will be created for every locale and you'll have to swap the whole application, i.e. reload it.

> When you internationalize with the AOT compiler, you must pre-build a
>   separate application package for each language and serve the
>   appropriate package based on either server-side language detection or
>   url parameters.

### Use [JIT compiler](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-jit-compiler)

This approach is less performant but you'll not necessarily need a bundle per language.
In this case you load your translation file with `webpack` and provide it to `Angular` compiler during bootstrap.

> The JIT compiler compiles the app in the browser as the app loads.
>   Translation with the JIT compiler is a dynamic process of:
>
> - Importing the appropriate language translation file as a string constant.
> - Creating corresponding translation providers for the JIT compiler.
> - Bootstrapping the app with those providers.

Although in the official documentation they only have examples with `useValue` providers, I'm pretty sure you can use `useFactory` to provide `TRANSLATIONS` and `LOCALE_ID` based on your configuration.
You'll still have to re-bootstrap your app upon language change, which, in turn, means reloading, but hey, the user have this bundle cached in the browser, so the reload should be pretty fast.

---

Anyways, as of now, if you want to get really dynamic translations I'd suggest you to use [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/).
Besides `translate` pipe and service they have this nice [speculative polyfill](https://github.com/ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill) that might save you some headache when code translations will be supported officially by `Angular i18n`.

Answer (score 5):

You can check that out, for me it works flawlessly and has great performance (instant translation with no loading time nor reload) :

https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate

You can then use a local storage or anything with that to set the language :

`translateService.use(window.localStorage.getItem('language'));`

You can set your translations in a single file, and you can order the translations in JSON format : (I encapsulate one object per component)

```
"PASSWORD_CONFIRM": {
    "TITLE": "Merci !",
    "DESCRIPTION": "Votre nouveau mot de passe a bien été enregistré. Vous pouvez désormais accéder à la plateforme !",
    "BUTTON": "Entrer sur la plateforme"
  },
  ...
```

and then you can set your text in your HTML as follow :

```
  <div class="title">{{'PASSWORD_CONFIRM.TITLE' | translate}}</div>
  <div class="description">
      {{'PASSWORD_CONFIRM.DESCRIPTION' | translate}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I really wanted to use the official Angular 2 support for internationalization. This is a solution though, and I will be using it if I don't find an alternative. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Andre, Did you find any solution for your question as i also want to implement the same for my application

Comment: Seem like official angular i18n will support dynamic translation with the release of ivy. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477

Comment: I ended up doing both.. using the i18n angular for static texts, and ngx-translate for anything containing html tags, or that needs to be used in components. HTML tags in xlif is a horrible messy experience that I had to give up upon.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do this if you're using JIT compilation. You'll need a factory provider for your translations. Add something like this to your root module:

```
  export function localeFactory(): string {
    return (window.clientInformation && window.clientInformation.language) || window.navigator.language;
  }

  providers:
  [
    {
      provide: TRANSLATIONS,
      useFactory: (locale) => {
        locale = locale || 'en'; // default to english if no locale provided
        return require(`raw-loader!../locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`);
      },
      deps: [LOCALE_ID]
    },
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useFactory: localeFactory
    },
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf'},
```

Comment: With this method it's a 1 time decision though at bootstrap correct? (just verifying). It's not like there could be a dropdown with a local/country selection and this could be changed dynamically could it? It needs to be decided upon the provider being registered with Angular.