# angular 5 change locale dynamically for i18n

Tags: angular, internationalization, locale, angular-i18n

I am trying to change locale dynamically to change i18n language.
I have two files, the one with english values and the other one with french values.

What I've tried for now is something like that :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const localeName = localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'fr';
    import(`@angular/common/locales/${localeName}.js`).then(locale => {
      registerLocaleData(locale.default);
    });
  }
```

but it gave me the following error :

```
error TS1323: Dynamic import cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules.
```

Any ideas on how I can switch from english to french dynamically? :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 i18n dynamic/instant translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024207/angular-2-i18n-dynamic-instant-translation)

Comment: not sure if that a duplicate, but thanks for the link, i may have passed over this one. plus : the solution which is proposed in there does not work for me. it comples but doesn't do anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, not sure it's a good solution but here's what i've done. It works for my purpose so maybe it can help someone else.

in main.ts :

```
if (localStorage.getItem('locale') === null) {
localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en');
}

const locale = localStorage.getItem('locale');
declare const require;
const translations = require(`raw-loader!./locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`);

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations},
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf'}
  ]
});
```

in html code :

```
<a  mat-menu-item href="" (click)="changeLang('fr')">
    <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
    <span>FR</span>
  </a>

  <a  mat-menu-item href="" (click)="changeLang('en')">
    <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
    <span>EN</span>
  </a>
```

in component.ts :

```
changeLang(lang: string) {

    if (lang === 'fr') {
      localStorage.setItem('locale', 'fr');
    }

    if (lang === 'en') {
      localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en');
    }
  }
```

don't yell at me, i'm just a newbie with angular ^^

Comment: Hi, just spent some hours on a similar problem and understanding the main differences between standard i18n and "hot" translation of the page, I think a better result can be achieved by using https://github.com/ngx-translate/core