# language change / switch in angular typescript from a button

Tags: typescript, angular6

how can i change the language or switch language on a running project in angular 6
i want to change the language from ***English to Arabic*** or to some other language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 i18n dynamic/instant translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024207/angular-2-i18n-dynamic-instant-translation)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mechhanism like the following:

```ts
interface Languages {
    [key: string]: {
        heading1: string,
        bodyText: string
    }
}

const languages: Languages = {
    english: {
        heading1: 'TestHeading',
        bodyText: 'Bla Bla Bla'
    },
    someOtherLanguage: {
        heading1: 'HeadingInOtherLanguage',
        bodyText: 'TestBody'
    }
}

let currentLanguage: string = 'english';

function switchLanguage(): void {
    if (currentLanguage === 'english') {
        currentLanguage = 'someOtherLanguage';
    } else {
        currentLanguage = 'english';
    }
}

function getText(textReference: string) {
    let wordInLanguage = "?";
    if (languages[currentLanguage] && languages[currentLanguage][textReference]) { //check if word exists language
        wordInLanguage = languages[currentLanguage][textReference];
    }
    return wordInLanguage;
}

console.log(getText('heading1'));
switchLanguage();
console.log(getText('heading1'));
```

Note that the `console.log` is only for demonstration! In your code it will be something like `{{getText('mainHeading')}}` or someThing like that.

Comment: it's generally not a good idea to create your own solutions for a well studied problem, such as i18n